# How to download Independentsoft.Exchange dll?

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am looking for Independentsoft.Exchange dll but i cant find the solution for this please any one help me to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a commercial product [you need to buy](http://www.independentsoft.de/purchase.html).